# Extend gen_event behavior in Erlang

Tags: erlang, gen-event

I'm writing an event manager that will take a lot of different event handlers. This event manager will be notified with a lot of different events. Each handler only handle certain events, and ignore the rest. Each handler can also trigger certain other events based on situation.

For example, first handler to handle `Event1`

```erl
-module (first_handler).
-behavior (gen_event).

...

handle_event(Event1, State) -> {ok, State};
handle_event(_, State) -> {ok, State}.
```

Second handler to handle `Event2`

```erl
-module (second_handler).
-behavior (gen_event).

...

handle_event(Event2, State) -> 
  gen_event:notify(self(), Event1),
  {ok, State};
handle_event(_, State) -> {ok, State}.
```

The event triggering can be done by calling `gen_event:notify(self(), NewEvent)` within a `handle_event` of the handler, but I would rather abstract and export that out so that it can be called from the event manager.

Since pattern matching and ignoring events and triggering events are common to all the handlers, is there anyway I can extend `gen_event` behavior to provide those as built-ins?

I'll start with the default way to create a custom behavior:

```erl
-module (gen_new_event).
-behaviour (gen_event).

behaviour_info(Type) -> gen_event:behaviour_info(Type).
```

I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installed handlers are already running in the context of the *event manager* which you start and then install handlers into. So if their handle-event function throws out data, they already do what you want.

You don't need to extend the event behaviour. What you do is:

```
 handle_event(Event, State) ->
   generic:handle_event(Event, State).
```

and then let the `generic` module handle the generic parts. Note that you could supply `generic` a way to callback to this handler module for specialized handler behaviour should you need it. For example:

```
   generic:handle_event(fun ?MODULE:callback/2, Event, State)...
```

and so on.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating more? Or give me an example? Is `generic` also an event handler that I have to add to the *event manager*? And how generic parts be passed down to the `generic` module? I guess I still don't see the application here.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do exactly? I could not understand from the examples you provided. In second_handler's `handle_event/2`, `Event1` is unbound. Also, does using `self()` work? Shouldn't that be the registered name of the manager. Not sure whether `handle_event/2` gets executed by the manager or each handler process (but the latter makes more sense).

By implementing your `gen_new_event` module, you are implementing a handler (i.e. a callback module), and not an event manager. The fact that you have `-behaviour(gen_event)` means that you're asking the compiler to check that `gen_new_event` actually implements all the functions listed by `gen_event:behaviour_info(callbacks)`, thereby making `gen_new_event` an eligible handler which you *could* add to an event manager via `gen_event:add_handler(manager_registered_name, gen_new_event, [])`.

Now, if you take away `-behaviour (gen_event)`, `gen_new_event` no longer has to implement the following functions:

```
35> gen_event:behaviour_info(callbacks).   
[{init,1},
 {handle_event,2},
 {handle_call,2},
 {handle_info,2},
 {terminate,2},
 {code_change,3}]
```

You could make `gen_new_event` a behaviour (i.e. an interface) by adding more functions which you will be requiring any module which uses `-behaviour(gen_new_event)` to implement:

```
-module (gen_new_event).
-export([behaviour_info/1]).

behaviour_info(callbacks) -> 
    [{some_fun, 2}, {some_other_fun, 3} | gen_event:behaviour_info(callbacks)].
```

Now, if in some module, for e.g. `-module(example)`, you add the attribute `-behaviour(gen_new_event)`, then the module `example` will have to implement all the `gen_event` callback functions + `some_fun/2` and `some_other_fun/3`.

I doubt that's what you were looking for, but your last example seemed to suggest that you wanted to implement a behaviour. Note that, all you're doing by implementing a behaviour is requiring other modules to implement certain functions should they use `-behaviour(your_behaviour)`.

(Also, if I understood you correctly, if you want to extend `gen_event` then you could always simply copy the code in `gen_event.erl` and extend it ... I guess, but is this really necessary for what you're trying to do?).

**Edit**

Objective: extract common code out of gen_event implementations. So for e.g. there's a handle_event/2 clause which you want in every one of your gen_events.

One way of going about it: You could use a parameterized module. This module would implement the gen_event behaviour, but, only the common behaviour which all your gen_event callback modules should have. Anything which is not "common" can be delegated to the module's parameter (which you'd bind to a module name containing the "custom" implementation of the gen_event callback.

E.g.

```
-module(abstract_gen_event, [SpecificGenEvent]).
-behaviour(gen_event).
-export(... all gen_event functions).

....

handle_event({info, Info}, State) ->
    %% Do something which you want all your gen_events to do.
handle_event(Event, State) ->
    %% Ok, now let the particular gen_event take over:
    SpecificGenEvent:handle_event(Event, State).

%% Same sort of thing for other callback functions
....
```

Then you'd implement one or more gen_event modules which you'll be plugging into abstract_gen_event. Lets say one of them is a_gen_event.

Then you should be able to do:

```
AGenEvent = abstract_gen_event:new(a_gen_event). %% Note: the function new/x is auto-generated and will have arity according to how many parameters a parameterized module has.
```

Then, I guess you could pass AGenEvent to gen_event:add_handler(some_ref, AGenEvent, []) and it should work but note that I have never tried this out.

Perhaps you could also get around this using macros or (but this is a bit overkill) do some playing around at compilation time using parse_transform/2. Just a thought though. See how this parameterized solution goes first.

**2nd Edit**

(Note: not sure whether I should delete everything prior to what is in this section. Please let me know or just delete it if you know what you're doing).

Ok, so I tried it out myself and yes, the return value of a parameterized module will crash when feeding it to gen_event:add_handler/3's second argument... too bad :(

I can't think of any other way of going about this then other than a) using macros b) using parse_transform/2.

a)

```
-module(ge).
-behaviour(gen_event).

-define(handle_event, 
handle_event({info, Info}, State) ->
    io:format("Info: ~p~n", [Info]),
    {ok, State}).

?handle_event;
handle_event(Event, State) ->
    io:format("got event: ~p~n", [Event]),
    {ok, State}.
```

So basically you would have all the callback function clauses for the common functionality defined in macro definitions in a header file which you include in every gen_event which uses this common functionality. Then you ?X before/after each callback function which uses the common functionality... I know it's not that clean and I'm generally weary of using macros myself but hey... if the problem is really nagging you that's one way to go about it.

b) Google around for some info on using parse_transform/2 in Erlang. You could implement a parse_transform which looks for the callback functions in you gen_event modules which *have* the specific cases for the callbacks but *do not have* the generic cases (i.e. clauses like the ({info, Info}, State) in the macro above). Then you would simply add the forms which make up the generic cases.

I would suggest doing something like this (add exports):

```
-module(tmp).
 parse_transform(Forms, Options) ->
     io:format("~p~n", [Forms]),
     Forms.

-module(generic).
gen(Event, State) ->
    io:format("Event is: ~p~n", [Event]),
    {ok, State}.
```

Now you can compile with:

```
c(tmp).
c(generic, {parse_transform, tmp}).
[{attribute,1,file,{"../src/generic.erl",1}},
 {attribute,4,module,generic},
 {attribute,14,compile,export_all},
 {function,19,gen,2,
       [{clause,19,
                [{var,19,'Event'},{var,19,'State'}],
                [],
                [{call,20,
                       {remote,20,{atom,20,io},{atom,20,format}},
                       [{string,20,"Event is: ~p~n"},
                        {cons,20,{var,20,'Event'},{nil,20}}]},
                 {tuple,21,[{atom,21,ok},{var,21,'State'}]}]}]},
 {eof,28}]
 {ok,generic}
```

That way you can copy-paste the forms you'll be injecting. You would copy them into a proper parse_transform/2 which, rather than just printing, would actually go through your source's code and inject the code you want where you want it.

As a side note, you could include the attribute `-compile({parse_transform, tmp})` to every gen_event module of yours which needs to be parse_transformed in this way to add the generic functionality (i.e. and avoid having to pass this to the compiler yourself). Just make sure `tmp` or whichever module contains your parse_transform is loaded or compiled in a dir on the path.

b) seems like a lot of work I know...

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to help me! I understand that I could create a new behavior by specifying what functions I need to export, but I specifically want any module implementing my new behavior will acts just like an event handler, but with some of the common function clauses already handled (abstracted away from the people writing my new behavior module.

It just does not make sense to copy all the codes from gen_event.

My example just listed two event handlers, so the `handle_event/2` is executed by the manager. `self()` returns the Pid of the event manager, so it does work.

Comment: It could be that the manager is executing handle_event/2 as you're saying (I never checked this and thought that perhaps each handler executes its own handle_event/2). But anyway, I think I better understand what you want, and I guess there's no fixed way of going about it. I edited my answer with one possibility (but there's no reason something like macros couldn't be used I guess).

Comment: Hi, I tested it, and while it is really interesting, the return value of `new/1` of the parameterized module is not something that `gen_event:add_handler/3` would take.

Comment: Ye, that really sucks... although I did know that parameterized modules are kinda frowned upon... so if you can get through without them, it's probably for the best. Added some info on what I meant before when I suggested macros/parse_transforms in the answer.

Comment: I completely forgot, but as for the b) option, you could just use Erl AOP instead: https://sourceforge.net/projects/erlaop/. That will take care of doing the parse_transform for you and you just have to write the advices and where you want to inject them :)

Comment: I'll look more into `parse_transform/2` while testing with the macro, but yeah, a lot of work to be done there. The macro seems to do the job fine, but I'm hoping for something simpler.